# Continue program even after assert fails

Tags: python

I want to continue even after the `assert` statement fails. Instead of saying "File not found" I would like to ignore it and continue my program. I am unable to figure out the syntax.

Overview of the script and problem faced :
This script is used for downloading pdf from urls which were written in a txt file. I had used assert to stop the program if the file wasn't found.  It worked fine when all the urls in that txt file were working. The problem arose when there was a link which was dead and I didn't want the program to stop but instead continue to next link.

```
assert os.path.exists(of), "File not found at, " +str(of)
```

Program snippet :

```
for line in url_file:
  stripped_line = line.split(',')
  list_of_urls.append(stripped_line[2]+stripped_line[1])
  driver.get(stripped_line[2]+stripped_line[1])
  time.sleep(2)
  
  of = download_dir+"/"+stripped_line[3]+".pdf"
  fn = download_dir+"/"+stripped_line[0]+".pdf"

  try: 
    assert os.path.exists(of), "File not found at, " +str(of)
  except AssertionError: 
    pass

  move(of, fn)
  fns.append(stripped_line[0])
  ofns.append(stripped_line[3])
  status_file.write(stripped_line[0]+",File Downloaded\n")

url_file.close()
status_file.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: If you want it to continue, do you actually want an `assert` at all? Just just `if` instead.

Comment: Run python with -O to suppress all assertions

Comment: _"This gives error as well"_ - _what_ error? Presumably that you're not actually in a loop to `continue`? If you just want to do _nothing_ in that `if`, then why have it at all?!

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in your level of expertise, your learning experience or anything else about you personally - only in **the question**. Inexperience does not excuse you from the site's requirements. This includes [trying to look up information before posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and *clearly asking* a question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am inside a for loop. I have updated the question, please check. I want to continue to the next url even if one is invalid.

Comment: In that case you _should_ `continue`. Otherwise you run the rest of the block which presumably requires the path to exist. Or use `if` the other way around - if it _does_ exist, run the rest of the steps. Turning this into exception handling is pointless.

Comment: As written, the assertion serves no purpose. Maybe the intention is merely to print a diagnostic if the file doesn't exist

Comment: "people just downvoted the question without even getting to know the background of the question itself." People downvoted the question because they felt it either does not show research effort, is not clear, is not useful, or some combination of those things - like it says on the popup. Now that there is part of your program edited into the question, I still cannot understand the actual problem. **What happens** when you run the code? What is supposed to happen instead, and **how is that different**?

Comment: Also: if you do not want the program to stop if the assertion fails, then *what is the intended purpose of asserting it in the first place?* In your own words, what do you think `assert` actually means in a Python program, and what do you think it is used for?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. Your explanation of continue and if helped me. I have posted the answer which works.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This script is used for downloading pdf from urls which were written in a txt file. I had used assert to stop the program if the file wasn't found.  It worked fine when all the urls in that txt file were working. The problem arose when there was a link which was dead and I didn't want the program to stop but instead continue to next link. I hope this gives an overview of entire script and the problem I was currently facing.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if os.path.exists(of):
        move(of, fn)
        fns.append(stripped_line[0])
        ofns.append(stripped_line[3])
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited it, I hope this is the right way, since the script is now working in its intended way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use assert you can just us a `try: except:` block to catch the error thrown if the assertion is not True

```
try: 
    assert os.path.exists(of), "File not found at, " +str(of)
except AssertionError: 
    pass
```

However if your goal is just to print an error message if the file does not exist you can do:

```
if not os.path.exists(of):
    print("File not found at, " +str(of))
```

Comment: try except is giving Filenotfound error.

Comment: Is the error thrown by the assertion or by one of the lines afterwards?